# What can I do so the headphone volume is not so loud when I plug it?

Tags: windows-10, headphones, volume-mixer, logitech-headset

I have Logitech H340 headphones with a USB-connector.

When I plug-in the USB-connector, the headphone volume is too loud, even if I set the volume of my Windows 10 PC to one percent (less is impossible, zero percent is no volume).

What can I do so that the headphone volume is not so loud?

Comment: It might just be the headset - I actually use the same one, and I've noticed this too. Could probably attenuate further with Virtual Audio Cable or similar, but it's not free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also ask this question to professional computer users I know and they have always the same answer like @Bob has said in his comment.

> It is just the problem of the headset and you could nothing do for play it more quietly.